# A model send two same SQL but two different results

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a rails application with an association between Account and Record. An account have many records. I run the code with RSpec.

I have this function in the Account class :

```
data = records
puts data.to_sql
puts data.size
```

I have this result :

```
SELECT "records".* FROM "records"  WHERE "records"."account_id" = 1
4
```

But when I have this function :

```
data = Record.where(:account_id => 1)
puts data.to_sql
puts data.size
```

I have this result :

```
SELECT "records".* FROM "records"  WHERE "records"."account_id" = 1
0
```

It's exaclty the same request but I don't have the same result. Why???

Finally, I want to do something like this :

```
records.group(:category_id)
```

I must have all my records grouped by category but I have an empty result.

Do you have a solution for me?

Comment: Is your code on GitHub or SourceForge so we can look at it in more detail? There's definitely something screwy going on here, but I can't tell what it is from what you've posted. I'd really like to see the model definitions and the specs, at a minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

In my spec file I changed that :

```
before {@account = Account.create}
```

for that :

```
before {@account = Factory.create(:account)}
```

My account was invalid. I don't understand the real problem but it's working.

Thanks for all.